# How to write Spring Data JPA repository & entity to join two tables and where clause with multiple conditions

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I'm able to join the two entities Employee and Department using primary key relation using @OneToOne in Spring Data JPA and achieved the result, but I don't know how to apply the where clause to my requirement. Below is the query

```
select * from 
  Employee e1,
  Department d1
Where e1.emp_id = d1.dep_id
  And d1.crtn_time between to_date('08-NOV-2017 00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi') 
  And to_date('08-NOV-2017 20:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')
  And e1.EMP_CODE='10' and e1.Desg='Clerk'
```

I was able to get the results till this condition Where e1.emp_id = d1.dep_id as shown below code for two entities using one to one mapping.

Repository:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, transactionManager = "empDataTxnManager")
public interface EmpRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
}
```

Employee: Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "Emp_Code")
    private String empCode;
    @Column(name = "Desg")
    private String desg;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade=CascadeType.ALL, 
            mappedBy="emp")
    private Department department;

    ---- getters & setters omitted
```

Department Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Department")
public class Department {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "dep_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "crtn_time")
    private String crtnTime;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id")
    private Employee emp;

    ----getters & setters omitted
```

My question is how to apply rest of the 'AND' conditions after where clause in Repository class. Like any QueryByMethod (or) Criteria to write in Repository or Service class.

How can I achieve the complete results for the given query.

I referred spring data jpa documentation but I'm unable to find the exact solution for this.

Please suggest if any existing example to refer to achieve  for this requirement

Thanks

Comment: I could not understand what you want exactly.
Would be something like this?

    

`@Query("select e1 from Employee e1, Department d1 Where e1.id = d1.id And d1.crtnTime between ?1 And ?2 And e1.empCode='10' and e1.desg='Clerk'")
    Employee findCuston(Date before, Date after);`

Comment: @HenriqueFernandesCipriano  Yes, I'm looking for something to create query for two entities. Can I get the result by using your approach above ? Can I define this in my repository class. If so, don't I need to mention department entity? Please suggest

Comment: I am confused with your join statement `e1.emp_id = d1.dep_id` how can you match emp_id with dep_id are they supposed to be different ? Another point is Employee to Department relation has to be Many to One coz many employees can work for one department. If you are using the above code just for example then please use different one

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following on your repository:

```
public class YourRepo extends Serializable{
...
   public List<Entity> findEntities( Type parameter ) {
        List<Entity> resultList = new ArrayList<Entity>();
        Entity e;
        String sqlQuery = buildDynamicQuery(); // Build your complex where
        TypedQuery<Object[]> q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery( sqlQuery , Object[].class ); //Extract custom info from both tables.
        q.setParameter( "parameterName", parameter );

        for ( Object[] element : q.getResultList() ) {
            e= new Entity();
            e.setAtribute1( elemento[0].toString() );
            e.setAtribute2( elemento[1].toString() );
            e.setAtribute3( elemento[3].toString() );
            resultList .add(e);
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}

private String buildDynamicQuery( HistoricoGIDFiltro filtroBusqueda ) {
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT filed1, field2, field3 ... FROM Employee e1,
  Department d1 WHERE e1.emp_id = d1.dep_id ";
        if ( look if it has an employ code  ) {
            sqlQuery += " AND e1.EMP_CODE='10' ";
        }
        return sqlQuery;
    }
```

> With the above code, you can create custom queries and extract custom
>   information from different tables.